# MongooseJS trying to populate using nested query operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a code:

```
const profiles = await Profile.find({ profileVisibility: true })
      .populate("products", null, {
        itemName: "Item 1"
      });
```

This works because I am trying to find itemName which is direct field of the Profile.
However, in the same Profile Schema I have nested object named lists which is a object with nested fields example:

```
ProfileSchema = {
 itemName: "Item 1",
 lists: {
  name: "name 1",
  price: "price 1"
 }
}
```

When I try to do this I get null (this happens every time I try to query nested properties):

```
.populate("list", null, {
        lists: {name: { $eq: 'name 1' } }
      }
```

Comment: `populate` is used to fetch data from another collection (ListSchema for ex). https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html - I am not sure this is what you have going on.

Comment: I am more about trying to query nested objects. The same thing applies when I am using ```.find({itemName: "Item 1" })```works but anything nested like ```.find(lists: {name: { $eq: 'name 1' } })``` doesn't.

Comment: Can you add a few sample documents as json into the question, and describe the expected output? Also Profile and Product schema codes would be useful.

Comment: Try `.find('lists.name': { $eq: 'name 1' }) ` - https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#field-in-embedded-document-equals-a-value